# histogram xlabel size fit problem in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
for i in files:
     histo = pd.read_excel(f'C:/Users/carvi/Documents/report/eden/distribution/{i}',usecols = ['FOCUS', 'GUARD','SPEED'])
     df2=pd.DataFrame(histo,columns=['FOCUS','GUARD','SPEED'])
     num=[df2["GUARD"]]
     hist=plt.hist(num,bins=10,density=False,cumulative=False,edgecolor='black')
     plt.xlim([0,100])

     plt.xticks([0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100],labels=['0', '10', '20', '30', '40', '50', '60', '70', '80', '90', '100'])
     plt.title('')
     plt.xlabel("GUARD",size=10)

     plt.savefig(str(i) + '_GUARD' + '.png', dpi=1600)

     plt.show()
```

[image]

for Unequal distributions, I keep getting this graph with doesn't exact match the xticks(?) and xtick values. How can I match each values that fits into the xtick values?

Comment: Maybe `bins=np.arange(0, 101, 10)` to have bin edges at exact multiples of 10?

Comment: Most probably your smallest GUARD value is around 49 (check with `df2["GUARD"].min()`). If you only specify the number of bins without a range, it takes the full range from `df2["GUARD"].min()` to `df2["GUARD"].max()` and divides it into `bins` equal-width bins